# Rejection handler in Executors.newScheduledThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler

I have a ArrayBlocking queue, , upon which a single thread fixed rate Scheduled works.
I may have failed task. I want re-run that or re-insert in queue at high priority or top level

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts here - 
Why are you using ArrayBlockingQueue and not [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) ? Sounds like what you need to me . At first set all your elements to be with equal priority. 
In case you receive an exception - re-insert to the queue with a higher priority

Comment: but I want to retry only once, not second time.

Comment: can show some code to do this with rejecion handler of Executor's.

Comment: Als, If reject it should re-execute. But if it fails again, then it should reject it.

Comment: I usually share ideas and directions here , and let the users experiment with the code. In case you didn't understand my answer - in case you have a failure at a specific "task" , you should re-insert this task back to the priority queue, with a higher priority, this will re-insert to the queue with priority level, as you asked. You can also mark the "task" that this is retry attempt #1, and decide that after N retries (let's say 3) you don't insert back to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing might be a priority queue.  Attach a retry number to the task.  It starts as zero.  After an unsuccessful run, throw away all the ones and increment the zeroes and put them back in the queue at a high priority.  With this method, you can easily decide to run everything three times, or more, if you want to later.  The down side is you have to modify the task class.

The other idea would be to set up another, non-blocking, thread-safe, high-priority queue.  When looking for a new task, you check the non-blocking queue first and run what's there.  Otherwise, go to the blocking queue.  This might work for you as is, and so far it's the simplest solution.  The problem is the high priority queue might fill up while the scheduler is blocked on the blocking queue.

To get around this, you'd have to do your own blocking.  Both queues should be non-blocking.  (Suggestion:  [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).)  After polling both queues with no results, `wait()` on a monitor.  When anything puts something in a queue, it should call `notifyAll()` and the scheduler can start up again.  Great care is needed lest the notification occur after the scheduler has checked both queues but before it calls `wait()`.

**Addition:**

Prototype code for third solution with manual blocking.  Some threading is suggested, but the reader will know his/her own situation best.  Which bits of code are apt to block waiting for a lock, which are apt to tie up their thread (and core) for minutes while doing extensive work, and which cannot afford to sit around waiting for the other code to finish all needs to be considered.  For instance, if a failed run can immediately be rerun on the same thread with no time-consuming cleanup, most of this code can be junked.

```
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue  mainQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue  prioQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
private final Object  entryWatch = new Object();

/** Adds a new job to the queue. */
public void addjob( Runnable runjob )  {
    synchronized (entryWatch)  { entryWatch.notifyAll(); }
}
/** The endless loop that does the work. */
public void schedule()  {
    for (;;)  {
        Runnable  run = getOne();  // Avoids lock if successful.
        if (run == null)  {
            // Both queues are empty.
            synchronized (entryWatch)  {
                // Need to check again.  Someone might have added and notifiedAll
                // since last check. From this point until, wait, we can be sure
                // entryWatch is not notified.
                run = getOne();
                if (run == null)  {
                    // Both queues are REALLY empty.
                    try  { entryWatch.wait(); }
                    catch (InterruptedException ie)  {}
                }
            }
        }
        runit( run );
    }
}
/** Helper method for the endless loop. */
private Runnable getOne()  {
    Runnable  run = (Runnable) prioQueue.poll();
    if (run != null)  return run;
    return (Runnable) mainQueue.poll();
}
/** Runs a new job. */
public void runit( final Runnable runjob )  {
    // Do everthing in another thread.  (Optional)
    new Thread()  {
        @Override public void run()  {
            // Run run.  (Possibly in own thread?)
            // (Perhaps best in thread from a thread pool.)
            runjob.run();
            // Handle failure (runit only, NOT in runitLast).
            //  Defining "failure" left as exercise for reader.
            if (failure)  {
                // Put code here to handle failure.
                // Put back in queue.
                prioQueue.add( runjob );
                synchronized (entryWatch)  { entryWatch.notifyAll(); }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
/** Reruns a job. */
public void runitLast( final Runnable runjob )  {
     // Same code as "runit", but don't put "runjob" in "prioQueue" on failure.
}
```

Comment: @Maverick: you mean the third idea, with two non-blocking queues?

Comment: @Maverick if you did, see the addition.  If you didn't the addition will probably still help.